# Why am I getting almost same top 10 features using Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier for positive and negative class?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, feature-selection, naivebayes, tfidfvectorizer

After running MultinomialNB multiple times I'm getting same features for +ve and -ve class BoW, TfIdf.
I even tried it on bi-grams, tri-grams still the same features for both classes.

```
best_alpha = 6
clf = MultinomialNB( alpha=best_alpha )
clf.fit(X_tr, y_train)

y_train_pred = batch_predict(clf, X_tr)    
y_test_pred = batch_predict(clf, X_te)

train_fpr, train_tpr, tr_thresholds = roc_curve(y_train, y_train_pred)
test_fpr, test_tpr, te_thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_pred)
```

This is the code for getting top 10 features for positive and negative classes of text data Tf-Idf.
`feats_tfidf` contains the features of categorical, numerical and text data.

For Positive class

```
sorted_idx = np.argsort( clf.feature_log_prob_[1] )[-10:]

for p,q in zip(feats_tfidf[ sorted_idx ], clf.feature_log_prob_[1][ sorted_idx ]):
print('{:45}:{}'.format(p,q))
```

Output:

```
Mathematics                                  :-7.134937347073638
Literacy                                     :-6.910334729871051
Grades_3_5                                   :-6.832969821702653
Ms                                           :-6.791634814736902
Math_Science                                 :-6.748584860699069
Grades_PreK_2                                :-6.664767807632341
Literacy_Language                            :-6.4833650280402875
Mrs                                          :-6.404885953106168
Teacher number of previously posted projects :-3.285663623429455
price                                        :-0.09775430166978438
```

For negative class

```
sorted_idx = np.argsort( clf.feature_log_prob_[0] )[-10:]

for p,q in zip(feats_tfidf[ sorted_idx ], clf.feature_log_prob_[0][ sorted_idx ]):
print('{:45}:{}'.format(p,q))
```

Output:

```
Literacy                                     :-7.31906682336635
Mathematics                                  :-7.318545582802034
Grades_3_5                                   :-7.088236519755028
Ms                                           :-6.970453484098645
Math_Science                                 :-6.887189615718408
Grades_PreK_2                                :-6.85882128589294
Literacy_Language                            :-6.8194613665941155
Mrs                                          :-6.648860662073821
Teacher number of previously posted projects :-4.008908256269724
price                                        :-0.08131982830664697
```

Please help me someone is it correct way of doing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this
sorted_idx = np.argsort(-1 * clf_bow.feature_log_prob_[0] )[0:11] 
for i in sorted_idx:
    print(count_vect.get_feature_names()[i])

When you say [-10:] you would be printing elements in position (n-10), (n-9)....n
but we would want elements to be printed are n, n-1, n-2,... n-10

Comment: It didn't helped, gave the same result as the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem, and yes I too got many top features that are common in both the classes, though it's not exactly in same order as yours.

Here's how I did it - 
I first chained all the features and the probability values(exponential of log-probability) together and then sorted in descending order.

[top 10 Positive class features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFGIN.png)

[top 10 Negative class features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zvUV.png)

So yes, I think what you're getting is correct.